# How to return results that have multiple records tied to it, filtering out the rows that only have 1 result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

| PayID | userclass | category | paydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 111 | 7 | 1/1/2022 |
| 91 | 111 | 7 | 3/1/2022 |
| 92 | 222 | 8 | 2/1/2022 |
| 93 | 333 | 8 | 2/1/2022 |
| 94 | 444 | 9 | 3/15/2022 |
| 95 | 444 | 9 | 4/1/2022 |

So I want to write a SQL query that allows me to result with the records associated with payIDs 90,91,94 and 95 because I want records associated with multiple paydates of the same category within the same userclass.

--
So far I can get the entirety of the queried results as show in the example above

With my structure being something like:

```
SELECT
  p.payID,
  p.userclass,
  pc.category,
  p.paydate
FROM
  pay p 
    INNER JOIN paycategory pc
       ON p.categoryID = pc.categoryID
```

Which shows everything but not filtered down to the 4 records I want to be output.
i.e

| PayID | userclass | category | paydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 111 | 7 | 1/1/2022 |
| 91 | 111 | 7 | 3/1/2022 |
| 94 | 444 | 9 | 3/15/2022 |
| 95 | 444 | 9 | 4/1/2022 |

I think I need to use the count function or something along that line but I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: What engine are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? etc.?

Comment: Sorry, paycategory is another table I join in to bring in additional fields for my final query. I put it in there to give some context to how my query is being structured so far. To answer your question it would be a table that joins in that shows what the category id is tied to the name of the category ie category 7 = Full Time Pay, 8 = Part Time Pay etc.

Comment: MS SQL Server is what I'm using

Comment: Let's pretend that userclass 333 is 222. Would you still want that in your results? It would have multiple payids, but both on the same paydate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` using `DENSE_RANK()` along with `EXISTS` to achieve this:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  
    p.payID,
    p.userclass,
    pc.category,
    p.paydate,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.userclass, pc.category ORDER BY payID) AS dr
  FROM pay p 
  INNER JOIN paycategory pc ON p.categoryID = pc.categoryID)
SELECT 
    a.payID,
    a.userclass,
    a.category,
    a.paydate
  FROM cte a 
  WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM cte b WHERE a.userclass = b.userclass and a.category = b.category
    AND dr > 1)
```

**Result:**

```
| payID | userclass | category | paydate   |
|-------|-----------|----------|-----------|
| 90    | 111       | 7        | 1/1/2022  |
| 91    | 111       | 7        | 3/1/2022  |
| 94    | 444       | 9        | 3/15/2022 |
| 95    | 444       | 9        | 4/1/2022  |
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MUWf1Q4s).**

Comment: Thank you this aligns with what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem! Since you're new here, you should read this: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for future questions of yours.

Answer (score 1):

We use window function `count() over()` and select the results where there are multiple records per `userclass` and `category`.

```
select  PayID
       ,userclass
       ,category
       ,paydate
from 
(
select  *
       ,count(*) over(partition by userclass, category) as cnt
from    t
) t
where   cnt > 1
```

| PayID | userclass | category | paydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 90 | 111 | 7 | 2022-01-01 |
| 91 | 111 | 7 | 2022-03-01 |
| 94 | 444 | 9 | 2022-03-15 |
| 95 | 444 | 9 | 2022-04-01 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uIcnObvZ)